# geom_text_repel labels/leader lines not lining up to some points, ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, ggrepel

I am trying to attach labels to the last/only data point in each of the series associated with my graph using geom_text_repel. I am using position_jitterdodge() to eliminate overlap between points and have specified this as a position for all point/line/text features. Some of my labels look just fine however some don't, such as the far left label for plot 2231 (it should associate with the far left red circle). Does anyone have any input into how I might resolve this problem?

Code:

```
ggplot(data = LGR_Data1, aes(x = Proj_Year, y = Max_Tidbit_Temp, group = PermID, color = `CTRL/LOGJ`, shape = `CTRL/LOGJ`, fill = `CTRL/LOGJ`, linetype = `CTRL/LOGJ`)) + 
  geom_line(position = position_jitterdodge(0.05)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(0.05)) + 
  labs(x = "Project Year", y = "Maximum LGR Temperature (°C)")+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-3,3,1)) + 
  geom_text_repel(data = subset(LGR_Data1[LGR_Data1$YearID %in% c("15N2231","19N1301", "19N1302", "15N1303", "19N1304", "19N1306", "15N307", "15N1310", "19N1312", "19N1313", "19N2124", "19N2125", "19N2230",  "19N2326", "19N2328", "16N2329", "19N2344", "19N3331", "16N3342", "16N3343", "19N3439", "16NC002", "17NC003", "17NC004"), ]), aes(label = PermID, fontface = "bold"), size = 1, color = "black", segment.color = "grey55", segment.size = 0.1, box.padding = 0.5, point.padding = 0.5, direction = "y", position = position_jitterdodge(0.05))
```

Data:

```
LGR_Data1 <-
structure(list(PermID = c("1301", "1303", "1304", "1310", "1313", 
"2124", "1307", "2124", "2230", "2124", "2230", "2326", "2328", 
"1301", "1302", "1304", "1313", "1312", "1301", "1302", "1313", 
"2124", "2230", "2326", "2328", "1312", "1306", "1304", "2344", 
"3331", "3439", "2231", "3343", "2125", "2329", "2344", "3331", 
"3342", "3343", "3439", "C003", "C004", "C002", "2344", "3439", 
"2125", "C003", "C004", "2344", "3331", "3439", "2125", "2125", 
"2344", "3331", "3439"), Proj_Year = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -3, 
-1, -2, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 3, 3, 3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, 
-2, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), `CTRL/LOGJ` = c("LOGJ", 
"LOGJ", "LOGJ", "LOGJ", "LOGJ", "LOGJ", "LOGJ", "LOGJ", "LOGJ", 
"LOGJ", "LOGJ", "LOGJ", "LOGJ", "LOGJ", "LOGJ", "LOGJ", "LOGJ", 
"LOGJ", "LOGJ", "LOGJ", "LOGJ", "LOGJ", "LOGJ", "LOGJ", "LOGJ", 
"LOGJ", "LOGJ", "LOGJ", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", 
"CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", 
"CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", 
"CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL", "CTRL"), YearID = c("15N1301", 
"15N1303", "15N1304", "15N1310", "15N1313", "15N2124", "15N1307", 
"16N2124", "16N3230", "17N2124", "17N2230", "17N2326", "17N2328", 
"18N1301", "18N1302", "18N1304", "18N1313", "18N1312", "19N1301", 
"19N1302", "19N1313", "19N2124", "19N2230", "19N2326", "19N2328", 
"19N1312", "19N1306", "19N1304", "15N2344", "15N3332", "15N3439", 
"15N2231", "15N3343", "16N2125", "16N2329", "16NC001", "16N3331", 
"16N3342", "16N3343", "16N3439", "16NC003", "16NC004", "16NC002", 
"17NC001", "17N3439", "17N2125", "17NC003", "17NC004", "18N2344", 
"18N3331", "18N3439", "18N2125", "19N2125", "19N2344", "19N3331", 
"19N3439"), Max_Tidbit_Temp = c(23.857, 24.605, 24.002, 24.098, 
24.243, 23.665, 24.026, 22.8, 22.824, 21.915, 21.891, 17.938, 
32.021, 23.136, 23.472, 23.256, 23.28, 23.28, 22.345, 22.513, 
22.465, 22.705, 19.698, 15.223, 18.39, 22.465, 23.016, 22.489, 
23.761, 24.388, 24.315, 23.93, 24.171, 23.16, 22.513, 22.824, 
23.352, 23.569, 23.328, 23.208, 23.112, 23.232, 22.896, 21.963, 
22.178, 22.13, 22.082, 22.25, 23.665, 24.146, 23.93, 24.002, 
23.016, 22.776, 23.448, 23.088)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -56L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(PermID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Proj_Year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `CTRL/LOGJ` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), YearID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Max_Tidbit_Temp = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

[image: Example graphic]